# CSS coding not applying to <a>

Tags: html, css

It will Apply to other  elements, but not the first one, no matter what I try It will not work, suspect its a missing tag somewhere

```css
.makethelinknice {
  animation: lnktscolor 120s infinite;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
.makethelinknice:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.makethenextlinknice {
  animation: lnktscolor 60s infinite;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
.makethenextlinknice:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.makethelastlinknice {
  animation: lnktscolor 30s infinite;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.makethelastlinknice:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
@keyframes lnktscolor {
    0% {
        color: #368588
    }

    50% {
        color: #593688
    }
    100% {
        color: #368588
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="TextBodyTW">
            <a class="makethelinknice" href="C:\Users\home\Scaled\404\Index.html">Projects</a>
            <span>,</span>
            <a class="makethenextlinknice" href="C:\Users\home\Scaled\404\Index.html">Art</a>
            <span>,</span>
            <a class="makethelastlinknice" onclick="openabout()">About</a>
          </div>
```

The weirdest thing is its working in the StackOverflow code editor, even though it is copy and paste. I feel like its something funky with divs, thoughts?

Comment: Right-click, "Inspect element". Take a look at the CSS and look for issues; greyed-out or struck-through rules, etc.

Comment: Your Question is not that clear
But i think you have a problem with the css ***a*** tag First - Check for valid href link(link is correct or not) Second - Try for both absolute and relative paths Then Definitely you will figure it out where is the problem

Comment: Good Idea, I upvoted, but unfortunately nothing pops out as not working

Comment: Nope :( In case there was an error I copied and pasted a working code snippit, and it did not work

Comment: You're missing the closing bracket for `keyframes` but other than that - it seems fine and working. What browser are you testing it on?

Comment: What browser are you testing it on

Comment: Vivaldi, A fork of chrome, however firefox and chrome do not work

Comment: Here it is in codepen https://codepen.io/ItsEvanB/pen/MWwYWoQ

Comment: solved the issue, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a double bracket which breaks the CSS. Just remove it

```
}
} <== this one
.makethelinknice {
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, you were just missing a final curly brace at the end of your keyframes animations style declaration.

I would also like to add that it was really difficult to notice the actual animation running due to the animation durations you set at `120s` ( 2 minutes! )

```css
@keyframes lnktscolor {
    0% {
        color: #368588
    }

    50% {
        color: #593688
    }
    100% {
        color: #368588
    }
} /* <====== you missed this curly brace here */
```

Comment: Fixed it! Unfortunately It did not fix the code

Comment: here it is in codepen https://codepen.io/ItsEvanB/pen/MWwYWoQ

Comment: Its meant to be long, solved the issue, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug with your browser, I tried it on codepen and it worked too. It may only work in frames, which would be weird, but it is working for me on everything I try. I also tried doing the same with plain HTML, on Google Chrome. It is most likely that your browser is more picky with your unclosed bracket:

> @keyframes lnktscolor {
>
> 0% {
>
> ```
>    color: #368588
> ```
>
> }
>
> 50% {
>
> ```
>    color: #593688
> ```
>
> }
>      100% {
>
> ```
>    color: #368588
> ```
>
> }
>
> **here**

Comment: odd, its not browser specific

Comment: are you using google chrome?

Comment: a fork of it. here is the code in code pen https://codepen.io/ItsEvanB/pen/MWwYWoQ

Comment: it is working when I look at it on the second and third one, is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

HTML:

```
<div class="TextBodyTW">
    <a class="maket" href="C:\Users\home\Scaled\404\Index.html">Projects</a>
    <span>,</span>
    <a class="maket" href="C:\Users\home\Scaled\404\Index.html">Art</a>
    <span>,</span>
    <a class="maket" onclick="openabout()">About</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.maket {
    animation: lnktscolor 3s infinite;
}

a.maket {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: none;
}

a.maket:hover,
a.maket:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: crosshair;
}

@keyframes lnktscolor {
    0% {
        color: #368588
    }

    50% {
        color: #593688
    }
    100% {
        color: #368588
    }
}  /* <====== CHECK THIS BRACKET */
```